# 3 select tags with OnChange (value)

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

I am trying to create multiple onchange dynamic tags but when I already use the value how can I still create an onchange?

If you see this example you will understand what I mean:

**js**

```
    $("#select1").change(function() { 
        if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
            /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
            $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
            } 
        var id = $(this).val();
        var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
        $('#select2').html(options);
        }); 

    $("#select1").trigger('change');
```

The problem shows up when I want an description for each of the values from the `#select2`

I am trying to achieve 3 dynamic tags, the textarea should only show the description of the selection in `#select2`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hW4Mm/)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to a achieve 3 dynamic tags, the textarea should only show the description of the selection in #select2

Comment: How should this 3 tags behave with each other ?

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/hW4Mm/1/ ?

Comment: No not exactly only the description of the value in #selector2 should be shown :(

Answer (score 0):

I have built a JSFiddle for you, if I understand your question well.

`$("#select2").change();` is the key factor, which is called on `$("#select1").change();`

*If this is not what you're looking for, please provide a more clearer description.*

**EDIT: Updated the JS Fiddle Below**

http://jsfiddle.net/hW4Mm/20/

Comment: No not exactly only the description of the value in #selector2 should be shown :( So only the content of the text area should change

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle for you - hope that's what you needed :)